# Backbone routing with arbitrary text

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a page being redirected to from external to the backbone codebase. It has two parameters:

- ID: An integer
- CODE: A random printable ascii string (no `#` or `&` or `?`, but can include `-` and always includes a `/`)

Not sure if `CODE` param is %encoded or not. Think I can get them to control that if required. But issue at the moment is just matching.

I am a maintenance programmer, not my app originally, so just trying to make code that "fits".

Most of the existing routes just take a single ID. e.g.

```
"account-edit-:accountId"    : "accountEditRoute"
```

But how do I pass my two params in to my process route. I have tried:

```
"process-:id-:code"    : "processCode"
"process-[^-]*-:code"  : "processCode"
"process-:id/:code"    : "processCode"
"process-:id/*"        : "processCode"
```

And my code handler is like:

```
processCode: function(id, code) {
...
}
```

I am always getting the unknown route handler. So how can I match the above.

Sorry if this is a dumb question - but they (wisely) don't normally let me near the front end, so all very new to me.

Comment: So I have worked around it by getting the calling page to %encode the `CODE` parameter when doing redirect. I then decode it in the `processCode` method. Will leave question open in case there was a way to do it in routing table itself, but have a working workaround now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to do it using the [`Router-route`](https://backbonejs.org/#Router-route) option with a regexp. The routes hash can only match simple patterns.

> Manually create a route for the router, The route argument may be a routing string or regular expression. Each matching capture from the route or regular expression will be passed as an argument to the callback.
>
> ```
> initialize: function(options) {
>
>  // Matches #page/10, passing "10"
>   this.route("page/:number", "page", function(number){ ... });
>
>  // Matches /117-a/b/c/open, passing "117-a/b/c" to this.open
>  this.route(/^(.*?)\/open$/, "open");
>
> },
>
> open: function(id) { ... }
> ```